# Why does SharePoint 2013 deletes my Javascript code when saving a page?

Tags: javascript

I have SharePoint Online hosted by Microsoft, individual edition. I noticed that when adding links with a hash (#) to a page, these links would not be saved. I thought it was a bug and decided to include some Javascript, either in a "a href" or in an input button. Surprise! The save command deletes ALL my javascript code (in the body, I can keep it in a different web part)

Am I doing something wrong or is Microsoft artificially limiting me because I bought the least expensive hosting option? I feel shortchanged! I cannot do very basic things!

Comment: Use the Content Editor Webpart or the Script Link webpart to add the javascript snippet to the page.

Comment: Also, make sure the page that you are editing is checked out first.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but I am using Script Editor and all other changes are saved. It's only the Javascript and the URL links (when they contain a hash) which get edited.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out the problem. I was reusing a page that I did not create, it was created by the Sys Admin. Once I started using pages I did create everything worked fine and SP stopped stripping my code. Still, it would be nice to have a warning message or something...